# C++/DirectX 'level editor'

Tags: c++, directx-11

I'm trying to build a level editor (or in general some tools to create assets such as materials) and I have a scene rendering to a window already.

My idea is to have a different window for each sort of editing option i.e. the main window for the level, a window for materials, a window for model/animation viewing etc.

My question is, should I be creating a new swapChain/renderTargetView/depthBuffer/stencilView for each window so that I can render essentially  different scenes to each windows? (I use each of the window's handles to do all of this)

I'm currently attempting this but it seems weird having to keep switching the render target/viewport/depth buffer and I'm not sure if it is a correct method.

Answer (score 1):

If they are actually separate windows then each of them will need a swap chain et al, otherwise you cannot render into them.

Comment: Oh good, and if they weren't separate windows I would have to use multiple render targets as different portions of the backbuffer?

Also, are there any heavy performance costs in changing the render target and calling swapchain->present for many different scenes per frame? I ask this because when I used XNA I found that many spritebatch begin/end calls did affect performance.

Comment: @DomW Not an expert in multiple windows, so can't say for sure. In XNA the spritebatches have quite a high cost because they switch texures, coordinate buffers, tell the underlying system to render etc. I would *assume* multiple swap chains wouldn't have that kind of a problem, but the only way to be sure is to test.

Comment: You can use multiple swap chains, etc., or you can subdivide a single swap chain using viewports.  Multiple swap chains will probably make your code simpler, so prefer that.  As for performance, it shouldn't make any difference for a handfull of windows.  If you have thousands of windows each with their own swap chain, then you might have problems because that would be very atypical driver usage.